# Azure Pipeline picking wrong Maven version

Tags: linux, maven, azure-pipelines

We have Azure Devops pipeline and Linux Based Build agent.

Installed Maven 3.9.0 on Linux Build agent and environment variable is working fine.

But when i run the Azure pipeline it picks up Maven 3.5.4.

When configure the Maven path in Azure Pipleine task, it's pickup correctly.

Tried restart the build agent.But it's not working as expected.

As environemnt variable is working fine for Maven 3.9.0. Would like to fix why Pipeline picking up apache 3.5.4 wrong version.

Yaml Pipeline:
Without custom Maven path to 3.9.0 (Pipeline picking Maven 3.5.4)

```
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'test Services/pom.xml'
    options: 'clean install org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:8.0.1:aggregate'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'pom'
```

With custom Maven path to 3.9.0

```
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'test services/pom.xml'
    options: 'clean install org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:8.0.1:aggregate'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Path'
    mavenDirectory: '/opt/apache-maven-3.9.0'
    mavenSetM2Home: false
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'pom'
```

Result from where is mvn and mvn -v command. Used the account used for running the pipeline.
[test@Build01 ~]$ whereis mvn
mvn: /usr/bin/mvn /opt/apache-maven-3.9.0/bin/mvn.cmd /opt/apache-maven-3.9.0/bin/mvn /usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz
[test@Build01 ~]$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.9.0
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /opt/jdk-17/jdk-17.0.5
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[test@Build01 ~]$

Comment: Please share the YAML/pipeline configuration you have already got

Comment: updated pipeline in main post

Comment: Which user runs the pipeline on the build agent? while logged in as that user run `whereis mvn` and `mvn -v` and share the result

Comment: Updated the main post with result of whereis mvn and mvn -v

Comment: Reonfigured the Build agent help to fix this issue.